# Jsoup parsing with Android App

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse the titles of the articles of [this site](http://beep.tv2.dk/nyheder) and display them in a listview in an android app. my code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> mTitles =  new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        processTitles();

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mTitles);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void processTitles() {
        String URL = "http://beep.tv2.dk/nyheder";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19").timeout(10000).get();
            Elements titles = doc.select("h2[class=title");
            for(Element title: titles) {
                mTitles.add(title.text());
            }

            if(mTitles.size() == 0) {
                mTitles.add("Empty result");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            mTitles.clear();
            mTitles.add("Exception: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

Despite reading lots of article here on Stack Overflow I cannot figure out why my app keeps crashing every time I open it up.

Comment: if you look at your log and see `NetWorkOnMainThreadException` then search that, and you will understand.

Comment: Posting the logcat would help people help you!

Comment: @user2229269 Please post you logcat always when you are getting such errors.

Answer (score 0):

As @wtsang02 points out, you're doing a network operation on your main thread.  Your processTitles logic should be done within an AsyncTask.